# rails csv generator not reaching the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv

I have in my controller a section that generates an array of Song objects. For each song object, I want to output some of it's information to a csv file. I found instructions online and followed them to the best of my ability.

The controller:

```
def index
  @stations = Station.all
  #csv crap
  @played = []
  Station.first.users.each do |u|
    u.playlists.where("updated_at > ?", Date.today).each do |p|
        @played << p
    end
  end

  @songs = []
  if !@played.empty?
    @played.each do |pl|
      pl.songs.each do |s|
        @songs << s
      end
    end
  end

  @data = []
  @data << "Song"
  @data << "Album"
  @data << "Artist"
  (0...@songs.length).each do |s|
    son = @songs[s]
    @data << [son.title, Album.find(son.album_id).name, Artist.find(son.artist_id).name]
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    puts "******************\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    puts @songs.inspect
    puts "******************\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @data.to_csv(), filename:"daily_report.csv" }
  end  
end
```

The model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  puts "fuck all"
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    options.each do |item|
      csv << item.title
      csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, the controller is never using the model to generate the csv, which it should be. I have to extra stuff in the controller to try to make it generate correctly there, but I really want it to generate in the model. Any idea why it never hits the self.to_csv in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Your model's `to_csv` method isn't being called because you're not calling it - you're calling a `to_csv` instance method on an array.

You need something along the lines of

```
ModelClass.to_csv(@songs)
```

and your `to_csv` method should be closer to

```
def self.to_csv(data, options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    data.each do |item|
      csv << [item.title]
      csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm a bit confused about what you're adding to the csv (for example why are the item attributes added twice?) but this should at least produce a csv.